Can the error response contain the line number when the problem is in the code in a `with` clause in R
The builtin with statement in R language allows calling code in a new environment using list entries for variables. Look at the simple example:
with (list(a=2.5, b=-7), {
 print(a+b)
 print(c+d)
})

R 4.4.1 generates the following output (omitting the usual helpful intro):
> with (list(a=2.5, b=-7), {
 +  print(a+b)
 +  print(c+d)
 + })
[1] -4.5
Error in eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame()) : 
  object 'd' not found
Calls: with -> with.default -> eval -> eval -> print
Execution halted

In this short code example, print(a+b) works nicely giving -4.5 and the subsequent offending statement is easily identified: print(c+d) tries to read variables c and d, which have not been defined.
However, when the code in with is longer, I would like R to tell me the program line which has raised the exception. Can this be done?
My best option so far is to define all code in a function and then call that function in the with argument. However this feels like a workaround and lexical clutter, so that I ask whether there is a better way.
